# Вывод на консоль элементов из xml

Tags: c#

Объясните, пожалуйста, как вывести на консоль данные из xml файла из корневой ветки. Почему-то выводится только название корневой ветки, а сами элементы не выводятся.

```
namespace Bank
{
    class DataLayer //выборка данных в xml файле
    {

        static string pathXml = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["pathXmlData"].ToString();
        static string pathTxt = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["pathTxtData"].ToString();

        public static Man GetManDetails(string name, string surName)
        {
            Man man = new Man(); //потому что возвращаем тип Man

            XmlDataDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDataDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(pathXml); 
            XmlNode root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement; 
            XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("Man[name='{0}' and surName='{1}']", name, surName));

            XmlNodeList list = node.ChildNodes;

            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
                man.ManInfo[list.Item(i).Name] = list.Item(i).InnerText;

            return man;
        }
    }
}
namespace Bank
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DataLayer.GetManDetails("Иван", "Иванов"));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

При вызове метода GetManDetails на консоль выводится Bank.Man., т.е. название корня, где хранятся элементы корня Man, а сами элементы не выводятся. Знаю, что необходимо использовать цикл, но все равно не получается.

Comment: С xml лучше всего работать с помощью LINQ

Comment: А что вы ожидали увидеть? Вы выводите на печать экземпляр класса Man, а он не умеет себя печатать (ToString не определён), вот и видите полное имя класса. 

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, нужно что-то вроде

```
foreach (ManInfo info in DataLayer.GetManDetails("Иван", "Иванов").ManInfo) {
    Console.WriteLine(info);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```